# how to load an image from imagebox without using a path

Tags: c#, winforms

Recently i finally code my program. It swaps images when you press a button. Now, how do i tell the program to get these images without using a path? If that program is gonna be launched on another computer, it probably won't work. Here's the code i used.

```
        string[] images = new string[] { "C:/(path)/cyk.png", "C:/(path)/nerf.png" };
        int currentImageIndex = 0;

        private void changebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentImageIndex++;
            if (currentImageIndex == images.Length)
                currentImageIndex = 0;

            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[currentImageIndex]);

        }
```

I realised that it didn't work before because i didn't use a path.

Comment: Pls be more specific and clear. If you want the images without the path, are they stored in the resources? Pls add what is the expected outcome. In another computer, is there a specific folder where the images will be(e.g. the folder of your application, etc.)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code is fully-functional. I have tested it personally:

```
    string _imagename;
    private void changebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_imagename == "cyk")
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.nerf;
            _imagename = "nerf";
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.cyk;
            _imagename = "cyk";
        }
    }
```

Add these lines to the load event of your form:

```
    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.cyk;
    _imagename = "cyk";
```

Comment: I am sorry. Yes, they are stored in the resources folder. The images should be stored in the folder of my application. Thank you.

Comment: @p0150n:       I hope you know about adding resources to the application in Visual Studio(adding the resources from Project Properties -> Resources). Are they added in this way?

Comment: @p0150n:       Just a minute. I am just editing my answer.

Comment: Ok, but your code makes the images unchangable once clicked on the button. I would want them to be able to always swap, no matter how many times or which image is loaded.

Comment: @p0150n:       Are there going to be just 2 images? Or there can be more?

Comment: It should have 2 images. I don't need more.

Comment: @p0150n:       Buddy, nicely done! I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Edit: hey, uhh. The button doesn't do anything when i click on it. I checked the names.

Comment: @p0150n:       In `Properties.Resources.cyk` and `Properties.Resources.nerf` add the name of your image instead of cyk and nerf.

Comment: @p0150n:       For your convenience, I have added step by step instructions. Pls see the answer again.

Comment: Cyk and nerf are the names of the images. I uploaded them as png, if that matters.

Comment: @p0150n:       Just wait. I figured out the error. Just adding the working one.

Comment: @p0150n:       I have changed the code to a fully functional code. I have tested this one personally so there is no chance of malfunction.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check that.

Comment: @p0150n:       Sure. Go ahead. I strongly expect a positive feedback this time.

Comment: @p0150n : If you want to convert to .exe. use 3rd-party softwares like Inno Setup Compiler or InstallForge or Advanced Installer. Resources are added automatically so you don't need to do anything additionally.

Comment: No, I didn't remove anything. Thanks again. Have a nice day.

Comment: Just add resources before building your project, rebuild it and then compile it with any of the above mentioned programs. If my answer worked for you, mark it as the answer.